# How can i find the co occurrence of words in a sentences with perl?

Tags: perl

is there anyone who can help me find the co occurrence of words in a sentence ? the words are listed in two different arrays, the idea is to find the co occurrence of the words in two arrays from the sentences.

example:

```
 #sentence

 my $string1 = "i'm going to find the occurrence of two words if possible";
 my $string2 = "to find a solution to this problem";
 my $string3 = "i will try my best for a way to this problem";

 #arrays

 my @arr1 = qw(i'm going match possible solution);
 my @arr2 = qw(problem possible best);
```

how can i write a program in perl to search for co occurrence of two words (eg. **going** and **possible** since **going** is in `@arr1` and **possible** is in `@arr2` for `$string1` that means both words co occurred in the first sentence) also the same in the second sentence ie `$string2` (since **solution** and **problem** co occurred in at least one of the arrays) but the third sentence is invalid ie `$string3` (since non of the words in the sentence occur in `@arr1`).

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take care of word boundary to not match `possible` in `impossible`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my @strings = (
    "i'm going to find the occurrence of two words if possible",
    "i'm going to find the occurrence of two words if impossible",
    "to find a solution to this problem",
    "i will try my best for a way to this problem"
);

my @arr1 = qw(i'm going match possible solution);
my @arr2 = qw(problem possible best);

my $re1 = '\b'.join('\b|\b', @arr1).'\b';
my $re2 = '\b'.join('\b|\b', @arr2).'\b';

foreach my $str (@strings) {
    my @l1 = $str =~ /($re1)/g;
    my @l2 = $str =~ /($re2)/g;
    if (@l1 && @l2) {
        say "found : [@l1] [@l2] in : '$str'";
    } else {
        say "not found in : '$str'";
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
found : [i'm going possible] [possible] in : 'i'm going to find the occurrence of two words if possible'
not found in : 'i'm going to find the occurrence of two words if impossible'
found : [solution] [problem] in : 'to find a solution to this problem'
not found in : 'i will try my best for a way to this problem'
```

Comment: thanks a lot, what about if i want to the number of words the are matched in the sentence, say more than one occurrence of the array element?

Comment: and how can i deal with word that punctuation? eg. can't

Comment: @aliocee: Not quite sure i've understood your first comment, but i've updated my answer. For words like `i'm`, just add them in the arrays.

Comment: what meant was how can i deal with array with the following content: `@arr1 = ("i'm going", "match", "possible" "solution");` which means the first element contain 2 words?

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @strings = (
    "i'm going to find the occurrence of two words if possible",
    "to find a solution to this problem",
    "i will try my best for a way to this problem"
);

my @arr1 = qw(going match possible solution);
my @arr2 = qw(problem possible best);

my $pat1 = join '|', @arr1;
my $pat2 = join '|', @arr2;

foreach my $str (@strings) {
    if ($str =~ /$pat1/ and $str =~ /$pat2/) {
        print $str, "\n";
    }
}
```